# JavaScript | Angular: UI Router $stateParams With Octothorpe Is Falsey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, hashtag, routeparams

#### Issue

I have an abstract route that looks like this: `#/app/lists/:label`.

Which is great when User creates a "label" of `'Breakfasts'`.

However, when the `label` value is `'#All'`, then `$stateParams.label === ""`.

#### Question

How can I get Angular/-ui-router to acknowledge the octothorpe (hash sign) in the literal URL of `#/app/lists/#All`? (`$stateParams.label`)

Allowing the User to add an octothorpe, such as `#All` or `#Public`, is a necessary convention I'd like to keep for the user. What can I do to get this "label" when this character is present?

Comment: the `#` is a control character in URLs, it can't be used as a part of a parameter, just as `/`, `:`, `&`, or `?`.

Comment: A control character in Angular/UI-Router, perhaps. But `window.location.hash` provides it as part of the string value; albeit, it gives you the leading `#` as well -- but the funny thing is that Angular *doesn't* give you a `"".split('#')` value such as `"All"`. It really just bombs on this $stateParams property.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode and decode that param to put a '#'.

While routing to the page `#/app/lists/:label` where the value is '#All'

```
encodeURIComponent('#All');
```

which will return `"%23All"`

and when reading the data you need to decode the same in code:

```
decodeURIComponent("%23All");
```

Comment: Right. But that means I'll need a `.safeURL()` method on the local or global controller and supplant its `return` in the `<a>`'s `href`. Which is ... annoying. Let me put it this way: I'm sort of asking for a solution so I can duck an architectural issue, actually, to avoid ChangeCost. Its beginning to look like I need to abstract the `"#{{label}}"` values so I can swap out the `#`in a single spot (with) and then perhaps write a filter/pipe to display it aesthetically for the user as a `#`.

Comment: well I tried adding a param to state and the value had a '#' in starting and it was working fine automatically. I mean the url was encoded to '%23' and decoded to '#' when reading in code using $stateParams

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a noob in angular. Just got curious seeing the question and found something like -- Hashbang Mode.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

[Hashbang mode simplified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPhdy.jpg)

Although I'm not sure whether this will help your situation.

Comment: @Samsull, really appreciate the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to help. I'm beginning to think there is no solution for this but to use different characters -- or send a pull request to angular/-ui-router with a mod to their RegEx. Thx tho!